# How to install setuptools for python27?

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools

I followed the guide, run the ez_setup.py, and I get an error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0×bd in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
>   Something went wrong during the installation.
>   See the error message above.

Where's the matter?
Please tell me how can I get this done.

Comment: `ez_setup.py` installs Setuptools for you. No need to manually run `setup.py` afterwards.

Comment: Are you sure that this setuptools distribution is for python2.7, not for 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This website](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#setuptools) lists pre-built installers for common Python libraries for Windows.

Please make sure you download the correct installer for the version of Python you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some of the setup Scripts does not have the correct encoding header.
The message you get

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0×bd in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

usually means that the interpreter tyed to encode a non-ascii letter with the ascii codec. 
Which never could work. You need to set the right encoding, in the

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Script file. So the error you getting is related to a specific script file (which usually is also in the error output attached) and that also should be the Script file where you have to set the encoding.